# Change the ownership of all files & folders based on search result

Tags: linux, unix, chown

I know how to find all the files & folders owned by a specific user, say `tommy`:

```
find / -user tommy
```

But how can I `chown` the files & folders to another user, say `peter`?

I know I can change specific files & folder via this command:

```
sudo chown -R peter /the/specific/folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
find / -user tommy -exec chown peter {} \;
```

Comment: Is it recursive? do I need the `-R` flag?

Comment: -R won't be needed as this find -exec command runs chown on every found file or directory

Comment: thanks for your help.